# ubuntu vim solarized terminal failed

Tags: vim, terminal

I installed the solarized plug, but the color in vim is different from what it should be.
the `:echo &t_Co` > 256; `:colorscheme` > soloarized; `echo $TERM` > xterm256color;
It just seems everything is right, and in Gvim, the volor is right, but in vim, there are some difference. How can it be?
[in vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eqzJ.jpg) 
[in Gvim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXX06.jpg)

Comment: you may set `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`, however the color may change in your terminal since not all the terminal uses the same 256 color palette. see   [document](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) and [source](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/blob/master/colors/solarized.vim). the recommended solution as the document says is setting your color palette of your terminal instead of using this 256 colors.

Comment: I tried `let g:solarized_termcolors=256 ` , it didn't work.

Comment: what does" didn't work" means ? color does not change, or not same as your `gvim` ?.  gvim uses their own 32bit color palette and your terminal uses 256 colors. check for ":hi" command and look for `ctermfg` and `guifg`

Comment: check the output of `:hi Statement` and if `ctermfg` is smaller than 16, then you have to change the color palette of terminal, if larger than 16 and if the color is different you correctly set  `solarized_termcolors=256`,  but your color palette of your terminal is different from xterm. so you have to write which terminal you are using since how to change the color palette depends on terminal.

Comment: the `:hi Statement` returend `ctermfg=64 gui=bold guifg=#ffff60`

Comment: oops, then you correctly set 256 colors, but your terminal's color palette is wrong. are there any option that can set your terminal's color theme?

Comment: also I recommend using [base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16), [base16-shell](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell) and [base16-vim](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim), which has solarized color theme.

Comment: I use gnome-terminal. I changed the terminal's color theme to solarized, but it 's still different from gvim.

Comment: Why do you expect TUI Vim to look like GUI Vim?

Comment: They share the same .vimrc, so there's only a little difference, but the color in GUI vim is more soft to look. I want to use TUI vim.